# Fully remove Django model from code, but preserve base class and data

Tags: django-models, django-migrations

I have a Django model, `FeatureSwitch`, whose base class is a [Waffle](https://waffle.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) model called `Switch`.

The `Switch` model contains various fields, and the `FeatureSwitch` adds just one more: `owner`.

In the database, the table associated with the `FeatureSwitch` model has two columns: a foreign key to the `Switch` table, plus the `owner` column.

I would now like to stop using the `FeatureSwitch` model entirely and only use the base `Switch` model.  The `owner` information is no longer needed.

Ideally, I would like to remove the `FeatureSwitch` model from the codebase entirely, to avoid confusion.  But all of the migration files make reference to it.

What is the best way to:

1. Ensure that the data inserting into the base `Switch` table remains as-is.
2. Remove the `FeatureSwitch` model from the codebase and associated table from the database.
3. If any of the migrations have not yet been applied in an environment, have them insert the data into the base `Switch` table rather than the `FeatureSwitch` table.

Comment: If there are models that have a foreign key reference to the "FeatureSwitch" model, then first reference them on the "Switch" model. After that remove "FeatureSwitch" model and run "makemigrations" command. It should work.